# Can you change the value of i in a for loop (java)

Tags: java, loops

If I were to make a for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=25; i++){
     if((i % 2) == 0){
          i += 5;
     }
}
```

Would I be able to change the value of i like this to where when i reaches 2, it adds 5 to the value so now i = 7?

Comment: yes, but in next iteration, it'll be `8` cause of `i++` in `for(int i = 1; i<=25; i++)`

Comment: You know you can just run Java code and try this out, right?

Comment: _when i reaches 2_ The addition will happen whenever `i` is even.

Comment: It requires very basic fundamentals of the language. You can just run your code and check the required things. Request you to go through the community guidelines so that you can make your question more clear for others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the value of `i` will be changed but it becomes `8` ,not `7`.

Because when `i = 1`, then the condition `i%2==0` doesn't satisfy and the `if` statement will be terminated without performing the addition. Then the value of `i` increment by `1`.Now `i=2` which satisfy the `if` condition. Then value of `i` will be `i=2+5=7`. Now the if statement will terminate and for the step expression `i++` the value increment by `1`.

So now the value of `i = 8`.